# Cypher dynamic queries for neo4j? How can I achieve that?

Tags: python, neo4j

I'm trying to make dynamically building cypher query with python. I have a list of dicts, that contains pair of Node name and Node value. I need to filter Node:Goods by related Node:Property. Let's say that **one** Node:Goods has **many** Node:Property, and I need to filter :Goods by :Property name and value. For example I need all :Goods that has a relation with :Property `{name: "Color", value: "blue"}` and another :Property `{name: "Material", value: "Oak"}` . For that case I figure out query like this:

`MATCH (g:Goods) 
WHERE EXISTS( (g)-[:PROP]-(:Property {name: "Color", value: "blue"})) 
AND EXISTS( (g)-[:PROP]-(:Property {name: "Material", value: "Oak"}))
RETURN g`

Python gets list of dicts and for each dict makes string `EXISTS( (g)-[:PROP]-(:Property {name: %s, value: %s}))`. It works perfectly, but what if I need to make compare between some properties? For example - price range? I cant assign a variable for Node:Property inside `EXISTS()`, also I cant use `WHERE` inside other `WHERE` statement. How can I query all :Goods with :Property `{name: "Color", value: "blue"}` and another :Property `{name: "Price", value: "> 190, <320"}` ? There is no problem to pass to query any arguments or build it dynamically from list of dicts, there is problem with my Cypher knowledge :). Please help!

Comment: How are you currently modeling price? Is it modeled as in your example, modeled as a range? Or are these discrete Price values?

Comment: Price is just a Node:Property `({name: "price", value: 42, oldprice: 38, changed: "23.01.2018", currency: "USD"})`  that related to Node:Goods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, you would be best served with a MATCH where you could use a WHERE for the range:

```
...
WITH g
MATCH (g)-[:PROP]-(p:Price)
WHERE 190 < p.value < 320
...
```

If that won't work for the way you're assembling the query, you could instead use a pattern comprehension, which will provide a list based upon a MATCHed pattern and WHERE clause:

```
...
WITH g, size([(g)-[:PROP]-(p:Price) WHERE 190 < p.value < 320 | p]) > 0 as priceInRange
WHERE priceInRange
...
```

(you should of course parameterize the upper and lower bounds of the price range)

If the pattern comprehension yields a non-empty list then the price is in range.

Comment: Thank you! This solution works as expected! Have a nice day!;)